# Static resources from WebJars on IBM WebSphere Application Server not visible

Tags: jakarta-ee, websphere, classloader, websphere-8, webjars

I'm writing a simple reporting web application using JAX-RS and AngularJS deployed to IBM WebSphere Application Server. Since it is really very simple I try to keep as little dependencies as possible, so I am not using any fancy framework server-side.

For serving static resources I wrote this controller. I keep them in `src/main/resources` folder.

```java
@Path("/")
public class Assets {

    @GET
    @Path("{path:.*\\.js}")
    public Response javascript(@PathParam("path") String resourceName) {
        return serveResource(resourceName, "application/javascript");
    }

    private Response serveResource(String resourceName, String contentType) {
        InputStream inputStream =
            getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(resourceName);

        return Response.ok(inputStream)
                .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, contentType)
                .build();
    }
}
```

So far so good.

As I use several JavaScript libraries (jQuery, Underscore.js, AngularJS), I wanted to make use of [WebJars](http://www.webjars.org). According to [documentation](http://www.webjars.org/documentation#servlet3) on webjars.org:

> With any Servlet 3 compatible container, the WebJars that are in the
>   `WEB-INF/lib` directory are automatically made available as static
>   resources. This works because anything in a `META-INF/resources`
>   directory in a JAR in `WEB-INF/lib` is automatically exposed as a static
>   resource.

When I put corresponding WebJars into my `pom.xml`, things stopped working. This is what I found out so far:

- WebJars are, of course, present in the resulting `.war` package, in `WEB-INF/lib` folder.
- `ClassLoader` used in my `serveResource` method claims in has all WebJars in its classpath.
- The `ClassLoader`'s implementation is `com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader`.
- None of the resources in present in WebJars in `META-INF/resources` folder is visible to the `ClassLoader`. None.

How can I make the class loader see the resources in the WebJars?

Answer (score 1):

For serving files form JAR `META-INF/resources` you need `WebSphere v8.5`.
Check this page for more details - [Web container configuration for JavaServer Pages static file access](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.iseries.doc/ae/rweb_jsp_staticfile.html?lang=en)

Use the following methods to locate your static files:

```
URL ServletContext.getResource(String path)
Set ServletContext.getResourcePaths(String path)
```

> **META-INF/resources directories of fragments under the WEB-INF/Lib
>   directory in the application WAR file**
>
> After searching pre-fragment document roots, the web container searches web fragments. A web fragment comprises a JAR file in an
>   application WEB-INF/lib directory. The JAR might include static
>   resources in a META-INF/resources directory that are defined within
>   the JAR file. To prevent the web container from searching
>   META-INF/resources directories, set the
>   `com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.SkipMetaInfResourcesProcessing` web container
>   custom property to true. The default value for the custom property is
>   `false`.
>
> ```
> com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.SkipMetaInfResourcesProcessing = true
> ```

**UPDATE**
Try to change your method to something like this (pseudo code, no exception handling):

```
public Response javascript(@PathParam("path") String resourceName, 
                           @Context ServletContext servletContext) {

    // make sure resource name starts with / and should be relative path to META-INF/resources
    URL url = serveltContext.getResource(resourceName);  
    InputStream inputStream = url.openStream();

    return Response.ok(inputStream)
            .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/javascript")
            .build();
}
```

See [ServletContext.getResource](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29) and [URL.openStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#openStream%28%29)

Comment: Thanks. I don't have `ServletContext` class in my dependencies (it is really very simple application). Is there a way around it? If not, what dependency should I add?

Comment: @KarelSmutný Updated answer with sample code. Dependency should be on javaee-api 6.0.